# conditional execution in less

Tags: css, less

By using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), I am trying to execute a conditional inside a mixing

Here is my code

```
.my-mixing (@isInverse) {
    .navbar {
        when(@isInverse) {
            .navbar-inverse;
        }
    }
}

.my-mixing(true);
```

it does not work.
Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `when` in the way you are trying to, it always has to appear after in the mixin-declaration. And you have to provide a fallback mixin, if the variable does not match the guard.

```
.my-mixing (@isInverse) {
    .navbar {
       .navbar-inverse(@isInverse);         
    }
}

.navbar-inverse(@a) when(@a){
   /* do something if it matches */
}
.navbar-inverse(@a) when not(@a){
  /* do something else (or nothing at all) */
}

.my-mixing(true);
```

I added `when not(@a)` in the second mixin, so it won't get included per se. You could as well place it before the guarded mixin to prevent styles from being overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following html...

```
<div class="navbar">
    I am navbar!
</div>
```

this is a working solution:

```
.navbar-inverse(@isInverse){
    // do nothing or whatever
}
.navbar-inverse(@isInverse) when(@isInverse){
    // apply styles for inverse navbar
}

.my-mixin(@isInverse){
    .navbar{
        .navbar-inverse(@isInverse);
    }
}
.my-mixin(true);
```

But if you would have shown your html and specified your problem more precisely maybe there would be a more suiting solution.

Comment: note: @Christoph uses the guard-order that conforms to the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions) but in practice it didn't work for me that way.

Comment: That's interesting, I tried it [here](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) and it worked. Normally the order should not matter.

Comment: Very confusing... now I also tested it at [winless.org](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) and your solution resolves to the **false-case on either input** (true/false). (Meaning that in the css output the false-case is always the *last in order*, thus overwriting previous styles.) Am I missing something?

Comment: True, a `when not(@a)` condition is needed if there are styles that can be overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I edited my answer to reflect or conversation. And I +1ed you answer (already yesterday) because your inverted order has a little less fuzz;)